# Generated Json from RestController is array of values and not array of map

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

> **UPDATE : Issue was due to JPA query was giving a output as an array and not the expected data model. Even type casting was not giving any exception. Consider the issue resolved/closed**

I have a bean class

```
public class Row {
    private String requestId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String status;

    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }

    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

I am getting a list of Row object and setting it into below model class

```
public class ResponseModel {
    private Object dataObj;
    private List dataList;
    private String errorMsg;

    public Object getDataObj() {
        return dataObj;
    }

    public void setDataObj(Object dataObj) {
        this.dataObj = dataObj;
    }

    public String getErrorMsg() {
        return errorMsg;
    }

    public void setErrorMsg(String errorMsg) {
        this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    }

public void setDataList(List dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
}

public String getErrorMsg() {
        return errorMsg;
    }

    public void setErrorMsg(String errorMsg) {
        this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    }
}
}
```

In my RestController I have

```
@GetMapping(path = "getData")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseModel getRecords(@ModelAttribute RequestModel recRequest) {

    return dataService.getSearchResult(recRequest);
}
```

I am getting a List of Row which then I am setting into RequestModel as dataObj

When reading this in UI I am finding dataObj is an Array of Array of String and not an Array of Objects.

I had generated a model object for as response in Spring Controller and it had worked just fine and was giving an array of json object (Map) and not just the  Array. I am finding this weird. Is this is because I am using RestController and not regular Controller. What would be possible work around to get the json data correctly.

The generated JSON is like this

```
{
    "dataObj": null,
    "dataList": [
        [
            "bozonprimarytest",
            "Shylock",
            "Grey",
            "chaos"
        ],
        [
            "bozonprimarytest",
            "Shylock",
            "Grey",
            "chaos"
        ],
        [
            "bozonprimarytest",
            "Shylock",
            "Grey",
            "chaos"
        ]
    ],
    "errorMsg": null
}
```

The expected response should have been.

```
{
    "dataObj": null,
    "dataObj": [
        {
            "requestId" : "bozonprimarytest",
            "firstName" : "Shylock",
            "lastName" : "Grey",
            "status" : "chaos"
        },
        {
            "requestId" : "bozonprimarytest",
            "firstName" : "Shylock",
            "lastName" : "Grey",
            "status" : "chaos"
        },
        {
            "requestId" : "bozonprimarytest",
            "firstName" : "Shylock",
            "lastName" : "Grey",
            "status" : "chaos"
        }
    ],
    "errorMsg": null
}
```

### Update

Tested this with anther Controller (reqular Spring Controller)
I am running my service with Spring Boot 1.5.3. The response was the same

Comment: Edit question and show the JSON you get, and show us what you expected to get.

Comment: @Andreas updated the question to have the JSON (expected and what I am getting)

Comment: *FYI:* The only thing `@RestController` does differently that `@Controller`, is to automatically specify the `@ResponseBody` annotation. Since you explicitly do that, there is no functional difference.

Comment: I am confused. If `ResponseModel` only has two fields, named `dataObj` and `errorMsg`, how can JSON have a field named `dataList`?

Comment: true I checked my code moving to a regular spring Controller as well and I am still getting same response. This is weird because I know this should not have been the response.

Comment: Please read: [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) --- Minimal means that you remove unnecessary parts of your code, to focus on the actual problem.

Comment: For the sake of clarity I have added dataList into the ResponseModel.

Comment: `dataList` is a *raw* `List`. Never use *raw* generics. --- *"For the sake of clarity"*??? That means it's not your actual code? How can we help correct you *actual* code, to get you the results you want, if you don't even share your *actual* code?

Comment: Usage of raw List is fine. Not an issue there because the intention is to keep it generic to accept any list. Issue in my case I am maybe that the list got generated wrongly in JPA. Testing the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because AUTHOR SAYS IT IS CLOSED.

Comment: True the issue I found is completely different to Json mapping